# What bookmark manager allows regex in search (and shows what folder the results are in)?

Tags: google-chrome, regex, google-chrome-extensions

I want to enter multiple search terms: programming, "software engineering", "computer science"; and get a results for links that contain one word or more.

Also, if it searches only certain folders (or shows what folders the results are in) that would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: These aren't regular expressions, looks more like keywords/tags...?

Comment: As I explained: I want to "get results for links that contain _one_ word or more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't *think* [LinkMan](http://www.outertech.com/en/link-checker) supports RegEx, but:

> What makes Linkman special is its sheer speed that allows you to find your bookmarks quickly. Just start typing a keyword and get results within a second, even with very large databases. By default Linkman uses wildcards and the AND operator to combine search terms, but you can also use OR, AND NOT and the "-" sign in your searches. Example: a search for news computer -games will find all links containing the keyword news AND the keyword computer, but NOT containing the keyword games.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]